# Unable to render output of an API call made from a text field unto the UI

Tags: reactjs

pls am currently building a simple UI using react on codesandbox. I just want the user to be able to enter an API end point in a text field and have the output(response data) rendered on a text area. Below is my codesandbox project link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-surf-6ygc5?file=/src/components/PostList.jsx. Your input will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small error getting the value in your `submitHandler`.

Instead of the user input value, you pass the string `"e.target.value"`, which is not true.

```js
const resp = axios.get("e.target.value");
```

Use it like this instead

```js
const inputLink = e.target[0].value;
const resp = axios.get(inputLink);
```

It also makes no sense to store the result of calling the `axios.get` function in the component `state`.
Immediately after the call, you can use then and catch on the result of calling `axios.get`

```js
axios
    .get(inputLink)
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ posts: res.data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
            errorMsg: "error retrieving data"
        });
    });
```

Thus, a minimal working component will look something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-fog-cr2zg?file=/src/components/PostList.jsx).

Comment: Thanks a lot xom9ikk. I just need a littleclarification on e.target[0].value  is that to say that e.target is an array?

Comment: @Abelinho When you submit the form, you get an `event` in the `handler`.
This `event` has a `target` field. This is the array that contains all references to `input`s within the form. But this approach is not recommended in React. Better to use controlled components https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components. In the example, I did not fix it, so as not to confuse you even more)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your missed to the target value of input text in the OnChange event for the Input. Please see the below code if that helps.

```
 <input
            name="inputApi"
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ apiText: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
          />
```

I have removed few of your code. Also i didn't do other functionality like error handling. Please add a try catch block to **Async** block

```
submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
          const resp = await axios.get(
            `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${this.state.apiText}`
          );
          // console.log(resp.data);
    
          this.setState({ posts: resp.data });
        } catch (error) {
          this.setState({ errorMsg: error.message });
        }
      };
```

Full code is here below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios"; //for making API calls

class PostList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    /**
     * the lines below are unneccessary
     * as the functions are arrow functions
     * and require no binding
     * value={this.state.api}
     */

    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      errorMsg: "",
      api: {},
      apiText: ""
    };
  } //end of constructor

  submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const resp = await axios.get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${this.state.apiText}`
      );
      // console.log(resp.data);

      this.setState({ posts: resp.data });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ errorMsg: error.message });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { posts, errorMsg } = this.state; //destructure the state object
    //console.log(res.data);
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <input
            name="inputApi"
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ apiText: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        List of Posts: {posts.length}
        {posts.length ? (
          <div>
            <textarea value={this.state.posts[0].title} readOnly />
          </div>
        ) : null}
        {errorMsg ? <div>{errorMsg}</div> : null}
      </div>
    ); //endOfReturn
  } //endOfRender
} //endOfPostList
export default PostList;

/**posts.map((post) => <div key={post.id}>{post.title}</div>)*/
```

Comment: Thanks Praga for your input. I appreciate